# Why can't an external keyboard or mouse wake up Windows 10?

Tags: windows, power-management, asus-laptop

In the device manager, I tried enabling the ability to wake up the computer but that tab (Power management) is not available for both external keyboard and mouse. I read that they might not support it. Or is it the laptop that doesn't support it? It's a Asus ZenBook UX430UQ.

The use case is that the laptop lid should remained closed while I use it through an external monitor/mouse/keyboard with the ability to wake it up. I checked the BIOS but found no related option.